# .NET escaping characters?

Tags: jquery, .net, escaping, decode

Is there any way to unescape these characters in .NET?

I am sending a string containing PHP code via ajax to a .NET method.

This method then sends it via an email but because they have been escaped in jQuery it looks like:

```
<?php print $test; ?>

Looks like:

%3C%3Fphp%0A%0Aprint%20%24test%3B%0A%0A%3F%3E
```

So basically I need to unescape it before it is sent via an email.

---

**EDIT**

Still cant get this to work, still wont send the content of the field.

```
public static string CreateSnippet(int processid)
{

    //here we find form values posted to the current page
    HttpRequest post = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    string email = post["email"];
    string comment = post["comment"];
    string name = post["name"];
    string website = post["website"];

    var DecodedString = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(comment);

    var mailcontent = new StringBuilder();
    mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Name", name);
    mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Email", email);
    mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Website", website);
    mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Message", DecodedString);

    // Send the email
    library.SendMail("admin@email.co.uk", "admin@email.co.uk", "Contact Form Enquiry", mailcontent.ToString(), true);

    //if nothing gets created, we return zero
    return "success";

}
```

Am I using this in the right way or is there a problem with the way I have setup the variables?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: This title makes my break explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `decodeURIComponent` on the string in javascript, or the equivalent of URL Decoding in .NET (`Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString)`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I use decodeURIComponent in javascript it wont sent via Ajax to the .net method?

That was the reason to escape it before the ajax request.

I need to do it in .NET. Just need to find out the way to do it.

Comment: try `Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString)` as the friendly editor pointed out.  I'm not familiar with .NET personally.

Comment: @Robert I edited into the answer the .NET method for decoding (this is contained within System.Web).

Comment: Ok, I have it setup like:

    string DecodedString = Server.UrlDecode(comment);

I also have a reference to System.Web, but it is telling that Server does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I am not a .NET developer.  Take a look at http://forums.asp.net/t/1140104.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

`URLDecode` is the *right* way to do it, but just for fun here's a regex one-liner:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "%(..)", m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].ToString(), 16)).ToString());
```